# Troubles understanding why maybe type signature in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, option-type, type-signature

Hi I am having troubles understanding the type signature that I need for my function.

```
-- findPassword :: Map.Map Hash Passwd -> Int -> Hash -> Maybe Passwd
findPassword rTable width hashVal = do
    let usefulHashes = take (width+1) (iterate (pwHash.pwReduce) hashVal)
    let hashesInMap = [i | i <- usefulHashes, Map.member i rTable]
    let goodPass = [ rTable Map.! j | j <- hashesInMap]
    let findPass = listToMaybe [ helper k hashVal width | k <- goodPass, (helper k hashVal width) /= "" ] 
    return findPass
    where
        helper :: Passwd -> Hash -> Int -> Passwd
        helper passW hashVal width
            | (pwHash passW) == hashVal   = passW
            | width == 0                  = ""
            | otherwise                   = helper (pwReduce (pwHash passW)) hashVal (width-1)
```

In this function I take a table which is a map of Hash values (Int32) as keys to passwords (Strings) and attempt to find a given hash in the table. Once I find the password that I am looking for I use listToMaybe and return the value as a maybe Passwd. However, When I run this I receive this error:

```
* Couldn't match type `Maybe Passwd' with `[Char]'
      Expected type: Maybe Passwd
        Actual type: Maybe (Maybe Passwd)
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: return result
      In the expression:
        do let usefulHashes
                 = take (width + 1) (iterate (pwHash . pwReduce) hashVal)
           let hashesInMap = ...
           let goodPass = ...
           let findPass = ...
           ....
      In an equation for `findPassword':
          findPassword rTable width hashVal
            = do let usefulHashes = ...
                 let hashesInMap = ...
                 let goodPass = ...
                 ....
            where
                turntoMaybe :: [Passwd] -> Maybe Passwd
                turntoMaybe list = listToMaybe list
                helper :: Passwd -> Hash -> Int -> Passwd
                helper passW hashVal width
                  | (pwHash passW) == hashVal = passW
                  | width == 0 = ""
                  | otherwise = helper (pwReduce (pwHash passW)) hashVal (width - 1)
   |
78 |     return result
```

So my question is why is it expecting a Maybe (Maybe Passwd) value? If i switch the type signature to Maybe (Maybe Passwd) it works but the output is expect a double Just Just "Passwd". If I remove the type signature it works just fine though. This is just a small snippet of the rest of the project so let me know if any clarifications is needed on it.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. This should include a `main` function that illustrates how this `findPassword ` function is called.

Comment: I suggest you learn when you should use `do` and when not to. When a function is just making calculations, you shouldn't use `do`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice This is already a minimal reproducible example. The problem is that its inferred type doesn't match the desired type in the signature, and you only need to compile the code to reproduce that, not run it.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica For someone more knowledgeable than me about Haskell, there is probably enough information here to give a reasonable answer. However, I am unable to reproduce the error claimed by the OP (https://repl.it/@codeguru/SugaryDarkRuby#main.hs), so I am requesting more detail so that I can play with it myself.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Even after clearing up the undefined symbol errors, the code cannot possibly cause the error shown because there is not a line that says "return result".

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Ah, I see. The OP forgot the imports and renamed a variable in the posted code. So this indeed wasn't quite reproducible, although for reasons unrelated to not having a `main` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haskell isn't Java. You're not supposed to end everything with a `return`. To get it to work, just change `return findPass` to `findPass`. You should also consider dropping the redundant `do` block and just using `where` instead of all of your `let`s.

Comment: This works thanks, would you be able to explain why I can't use a return statement there?

Comment: @cksssssss There's no such thing as a return statement in Haskell. `return` is just a function, and there's no reason to expect that calling a random function on your data would do something useful.

Comment: As a general rule, don't rely on experience in other languages to predict what a given function will do, especially based on its name alone. Look at the type, and read the documentation to see what it *really* does.

Comment: @cksssssss The (IMO) poorly-named `return` function takes a value and wraps it up in a `Monad`. So if you give it a `Maybe Int`, it will spit out a `Maybe (Maybe Int)` or a `[Maybe Int]`, or an `IO (Maybe Int)`. None of these, and indeed no value that `return` can give in this context, is the right thing for your function to return. These days, since `Monad` implies `Applicative`, I recommend using `pure` (which wraps values in an `Applicative`) where necessary over `return` because the semantics are better. That said, you need here neither `pure` nor `return` (and indeed can use neither).